# purging `falkon` removes `webhttrack` and `gimp-help-en`. Why?

Tags: debian, apt

```bsh
vrgovinda@krishna:~$ sudo apt purge falkon 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libhttrack2 webhttrack-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  falkon* gimp-help-en* webhttrack*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
After this operation, 74.8 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Why should purging `falkon` remove `gimp-help-en` & `webhttrack`??
This puzzles me. While installing `falkon`, no dependencies were asked even when `gimp-help-en` & `webhttrack` were not installed.

I'm on Debian Bullseye XFCE.  Please find the relevant details of my system below:

```bsh
vrgovinda@krishna:~$ uname -a
Linux krishna 5.10.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.46-5 (2021-09-23) x86_64 GNU/Linux
vrgovinda@krishna:~$ type -a falkon
falkon is /usr/bin/falkon
falkon is /bin/falkon
```

Please help.

Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`falkon` provides `www-browser`, which both `gimp-help-en` and `webhttrack` depend on (as an alternative dependency). Presumably you don’t have any other package providing that, so removing `falkon` causes the removal of `gimp-help-en` and `webhttrack`.

Installing one of the other alternative dependencies (`gimp-helpbrowser` for `gimp-help-en`, or one of the `www-browser` providers) will allow you to remove `falkon` on its own.

Comment: Thank you @StephenKitt! You are so learned!